# MessageBoxResult in class library

Tags: assembly, namespaces

**Hello!**

I'm creating a class library and have a general question: How can it be that properties of a standard namespace are missing even though the namespace is included by default?

Specifically, it's about the Windows.System namespace.

I want to implement a method in my assembly that returns a property of type: MessageBoxResult as a result.

However, VisualStudio does not recognize the Type: MessageBoxResult!

```
Error: IDE1007: The name "System.Windows.MessageBoxResult" does not exist in the current context
```

How can I integrate the System.Windows enumeration into my assembly?

I currently use my own enumeration that goes with the System.Windows. MessageBoxResult is the same (but is not good).

```
public enum MessageBoxResult
{
     None = 0, //The message box returns no result.
     OK = 1, // The result value of the message box is OK.
     Cancel = 2, // The result value of the message box is Cancel.
     Yes = 6, // The result value of the message box is Yes.
     No = 7 // The result value of the message box is No.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The System.Windows.MessageBoxResult enum is part of the WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) framework and it may not be available within every project type. If you're crafting a .NET Standard or .NET Core class library, then you won't have access toward WPF-specific types like MessageBoxResult.

To be capable of using MessageBoxResult in your class library, you need to make sure that your library targets the appropriate framework. If you're employing Visual Studio, you can alter the target framework for your project within the Project Properties window. If you're using a .NET Framework Class Library, you should be able to use MessageBoxResult.

If you can't modify the target framework and still need to utilize something akin to MessageBoxResult, you can maintain using your custom enum. You can map it onto the actual MessageBoxResult if you're using it inside a WPF application.

If you're developing a library that is supposed to be utilized across multiple types of applications (like .NET Framework, .NET Core, etc.), then it's a good practice to keep it independent from any UI-specific types. This would mean that you need to employ your own custom enum or discover another way of achieving your goal without the use of MessageBoxResult.

To manage message boxes and similar UI elements within a class library, it would be better to adopt an event or a callback to let the calling application determine how to display the message box. This way, the library does not need to know about MessageBoxResult and it can be employed in any kind of application, regardless of the framework it's built with.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation!
I want to develop the assembly exclusively for the .NET Core Framework as it is also developed exclusively for WPF applications. Up until now I have assumed that a namespace is a namespace and has nothing to do with frameworks.
Then my interim solution is probably the final solution after all! :-)
Thank you again for your explanation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, 
daniya shyanne!

All eight of your answers here since you joined 3 days ago appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.

Comment: It looks like this answer is generated by AI tools.